# Properties of Group Presentations

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose I have a group $G$ with a presentation of the following form

$$G = \langle g_1, ... g_n \mid g_1^{a_1} = ... = g_n^{a_n} = [g_1,g_2]^{b_{12}} = ... = [g_{n-1},g_n]^{b_{n{-}1,n}} = e \rangle$$

1. is it possible to calculate the order of $G$ from the integers $a_i$ and $b_{ij}$? Or to see if $G$ is finite or infinite from looking at $a_i$ and $b_{ij}$?
2. is this the most general possible form for a group presentation? (That is, is it possible to write all conditions like $(g_1g_2)^2 = e$ or $(g_1g_2g_3)^4 = e$ etc. In terms of powers of commutators of two elements of the group?) Is there some way to generalize this presentation to give a presentation for a general finite group?

For context; I'm coming from a background in mathematical physics where we learn about Lie group theory, but I'm only just learning about discrete groups. I'm trying to see if there's any way that it makes sense to port over my intuition from Lie group theory; for example the generators in the group presentation to me look reminiscent of a basis for the Lie algebra, and then the conditions in the presentation look something like a prescription for what happens to the algebra under exponentiation. Whether the group is finite or infinite looks like if the manifold of a Lie group is compact or not. Maybe these intuitive (to me) analogies are just wrong, I don't know. Any comments on this or related reading would be interesting for me.

Comment: No, this isn't the most general form. The abelianization of a group with such a presentation is a direct sum of cyclic groups and there are many abelian groups not of this form, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Also, there are groups where there are further conditions in the lower central series or the derived series that cannot be captured by putting conditions on just the elements and the commutators.

Comment: For example, you have a group $\langle x,y\mid x^5=y^5=[y,x]^5=[y,x,y]=[y,x,x]=1\rangle$ of order $125$, and a different group $\langle x,y\mid x^5=y^5=[y,x]^5=[y,x,y]^5=[y,x,x]^5=[y,x,x,x]=[y,x,x,y]=[y,x,y,y]=[y,x,y,x]=1\rangle$ of order $5^5$. If you only allow conditions on $x,y,[y,x]$, you can’t distinguish/describe these two groups.

Comment: It is not clear what kind of answer you expect for (1). I mean, you can calculate all the orders given this presentation (only because it is a finite group though). However, presentations are tricky and all you can say in general is that the order of the element *divides* the given exponent.

Comment: It’s not clear to me that the presentation would necessarily define a finite group, which should mean that you cannot determine the order of $G$ just from the presentation... it does for some values of the parameters (e.g., it $n=a_1=a_2=2$), but I don’t think it does in general...

Comment: And you wouldn’t be able to describe the quaternion group this way (or the nonabelian group of order $p^3$ with an element of order $p^2$, for odd prime $p$, in general).

Comment: Hi, thanks for lots of interest. What is the name of the bracket with more than two variables in it, $[y, x, y]$ etc., @Arturo Magidin? If I extend my presentation to include those brackets in some specified way, can I give an expression which will describe a general finite group?

Comment: It’s just an iterated commutator; depending on your convention, it is shorthand for $[x,y,z]=[[x,y],z]$ or shorthand for $[x,y,z]=[x,[y,z]]$. And, no, even if you keep adding conditions of the form “these commutators are of exponent $k$”, you’ll never describe the quaternion group of order $8$.

Comment: @user1729, the kind of answer I was speculating for my question one would be a function of the $a_i$ and $b_{ij}$ only. Does that make it clear to you what kind of answer I'm looking for? I'm happy to accept that the answer may be no. If it's possible to give an answer to this in a less general case, eg. If all the $a_i=2$  or something,  I would still find that interesting

Comment: Hi @Arturo,  thanks for your comments. I've edited my question to give a bit more detail based on some of your answers, if you have any response to it I'd be interested

Comment: For sufficiently large prime $p$, a Tarski monster (a group whose only proper subgroups are finite of order $p$, but which is itself infinite) would be a quotient of the group $\langle x,y\mid x^p = y^p = [x,y]^p = 1\rangle$. There’s just no way that you can assume such a group is finite, thought for some values of $n$ and the $a_i$, $b_{ij}$ it may be provably finite. And I already noted that the answer to question (2) is definitely “no”, and gave you examples.